# Change of variables and Tonelli applied to a negative function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following exercise. I believe I have solved the first two parts.  What do I do in the case of $f$ being negative? I cannot use the change of variables formula, or Tonelli for this. I assume I have to split the function into its positive and negative parts. How can I apply these theorems which are defined for a nonnegative function to a negative function?

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and that $f(x, y)$ is nonnegative. Put $g(x)=E[f(x, Y)]$ and show that $E[g(X)]=E[f(X, Y)]$. Show more generally that $\int_{X \in A} g(X) d P=\int_{X \in A} f(X, Y) d P$. Extend to $f$ that may be negative.

Let $\mu$ be the distribution of $X$ and $\nu$ the distribution of $Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\pi = (\nu \times \mu)$

\begin{align*}
 E[g(X)]\\
=\int_{\Omega} g(X) d P & \qquad  \text{Definition of expectation}\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)  \mu(dx) &   \qquad  \text{Lebesgue's change of variables formula}\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E\left[f(x, Y)] \mu(dx)\right. &  \qquad  \text{ Definition of $g(x)$}
\end{align*}

Now, expanding the inner expectation,

\begin{align*}
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{\Omega} f(x, Y) d P \mu(dx) & \qquad \text{Definition of expectation} \\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y) \nu(dy)\mu(dx) & \qquad \text{Lebesgue's change of variables}\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}} f(x,y) \pi(d(y,x)) & \qquad \text{Tonelli theorem (similar to Fubini but for $L^+(\Omega)$) }\\
=\int_{\Omega} f(X, Y) d P  & \qquad \text{Lebesgue's change of variables}\\
=E[f(X, Y)]
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\int_{X \in A} g(X) d P\\
=\int_{A} g(x) \mu(dx) & \qquad \text{Lebesgue's change of variables}\\
=\int_{A} E[f(x, Y)) \mu(dx) & \qquad \text{Definition of $g(x)$}\\
=\int_{A} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, y) \nu(dy)  \mu(dx) & \qquad \text{Change of variables }\\
=\int_{A \times \mathbb{R}} f(x,y) \pi(d(y,x)) & \qquad \text{Tonelli theorem}\\
=\int_{\left\{X \in A, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\right\}} f(X, Y) d P & \qquad \text{Change of variables}\\
=\int_{X \in A} f(X, Y) d P
\end{align*}

Comment: Where is your problem from?  The notation "$dX_*P$" is so uncommon (if you are still with Billingsley, he uses "$\mu(dx)$" where $\mu := P\circ X^{-1}$).  By the way, the expression "$\int_{X \in A} f(X, Y) dP$" is even more suspicious, I guess it probably means "$\int_A f(X, Y)dP$".

Comment: @Zhanxiong It is from Bilingsley. My question is on how to extend my argument to the negative case. I apologize for my strange notation. I was emphasizing for myself that this is the pushforward measure.

Comment: I see.  So he tacitly assumes $A \in \mathscr{R}$.  For the case that $f$ may be negative, I think the only condition you need to add is that $E[|f(X, Y)|] < \infty$ (so that you can apply Fubini's theorem).  You can mimic the proof of Theorem 20.3 to complete the proof.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I looked at Theorem 20.3, and I'm not sure how this would help me for integrating a negative function of a random variable. This looks like the theoremm is telling me how to find the probability of some subset in the image of a random vector using a type of fubini theorem-- which is similar to my part 1. How does 20.3 help with a negative function of a RV?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Is it the case that if the function $f$ is in L^1, then I also get the change of variables formula under that function? So I can essentailly repeat the same argumment I did above but using Fubini this time instead?

Comment: What I meant is trying to mimic how the proof to Theorem 20.3 applies Fubini's theorem and you may also borrow some notations from there too.  Of course, it will also be helpful to revisit Section 18.  If you think deeper, Theorem 20.3 is a special case of this exercise, just like the probability can be viewed as the expectation of an indicator function.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks I willl look at that. Aside from notation, did I do the first part correctly?

Comment: After the edit, the answer looks very neat! Just one thing, $\pi = \mu \times \nu$ is the consequence of $X$ and $Y$ are independent, not by "letting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions $f$ and $g$ are such that for each $x\in\mathbb R$, $f(x,Y)$, $f(X,Y)$, $g(X)$ are all integrable but possibly take negative values, then either the Fubini-Tonelli theorem or writing $f = f^+ - f^-$, $g = g^+ - g^-$ and using linearity together with a repetition of the argument you used for nonnegative functions provides the extension to functions that possibly take on negative values.

---

**Added:** Strictly speaking, we do not need to assume the functions are integrable, but we do require something just short of that. To fix ideas, let's just look at $g(X)$. By all accounts, we should be able to say
$$
\int g(X) = \int g^+(X) - \int g^-(X),
$$
but the point is that the quantity $\int g(X)$ is only defined when at least one of $\int g^+(X)<\infty$, $\int g^-(X)<\infty$ is assumed, to avoid having to assign values to expressions of the form $\infty - \infty$. Often, we do not work at this level of generality (though we surely still have occasion to), and instead we assume $g(X)$ is *(absolutely Lebesgue) integrable* in that we assume $\int |g(X)|<\infty$. Assuming absolute integrability, we may appeal to the "Fubini" part of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem, *or* we can use linearity just as well.

Comment: Do I need to assume they are all integrable if I use linearity? Couldn’t I just break into positive and negative parts and integrate?

Comment: @SamKirkiles: Good question. I added a bit to my answer to address this.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. What assumptions must I make for the first part?

Comment: @SamKirkiles: What do you mean by "the first part?"

Comment: The non-negative case which I already proved. Would it suffice to assume only the measurability of f?

Comment: @SamKirkiles: Yes, for nonnegative functions, measurability is sufficient